# Hartshorne III Proposition 10.6

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

The proposition is given as follows:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$. For any r, let $X_r=\{\text{closed points $x\in X$|rank $T_{f,x}\leq r$}\}$. Then $dim\overline{f(X_r)}\leq r$.

I just can't understand the first step:

> Let $Y'$ be any irreducible component of $\overline{f(X_r)}$, and let $X'$ be an irreducible component of $\overline{X_r}$ which dominates $Y'$.

I wonder why can we find such a irreducible component $X'$? I have tried to find the inverse image of the generic point of $Y'$, but the generic point may not be in $f(\overline{X_r})$... So I don't know what can I do to repaire it.

Comment: Let $Z$ be the closure of $X_r$, then $f(Z)$ is constructible and dense in $\overline{f(X_r)}$, so it contains every generic point of $\overline{f(X_r)}$. The conclusion follows.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks for your comment. By exercise 3.18 I know "a dense constructible subset of an irreducible Noetherian space contains the generic point", but I have problems on proving your claim, since I don't know whether $f(Z)$ is still dense in each irreducible component of $\overline{f(X_r)}$. Could you give an explanation?

Comment: Let $Y$ be the closure of $f(X_r)$. For an irreducible component $Y’$ of $Y$, let $U$ be the complement of all the irreducible components of $Y$ distinct from $Y’$. Then $U \subset Y’$ and $U$ is open irreducible (as $Y’$ is irreducible and $U$ is nonempty). So $f(Z) \cap U$ is still dense in $U$.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks a lot!